# Merging data in Calc

Tags: if-statement, formula, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have 1 spreadsheet with two columns: `sku` and `old_url`, and another with `sku` and `new_url`.

I want to make a new sheet with `sku`, `old_url` and `new_url`.

Some of the SKUs aren't in both, these should be discarded.

Is this possible?

Comment: Retagged. Excel should not be tagged if this is an open office calc quetsion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this could be done using ISBLANK(), OR(), and IF() functions:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C11),ISBLANK(E11)),0,J11)
```

Suppose sku_with_old is at C (and olds are at D), and sku_with_new is at E (and news are at F). This expression then is a way to get skus which are only in both... Similarly you can get olds and news in H and K columns.

Let me know if You'd like to make it this way - but can't.